# Swiftの画面遷移(コードのみ、アニメーションあり）とメモリリーク

Tags: swift, swift4

Swiftの画面遷移について

```
let animator:UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate = CustomAnimate(movePattern: animation)
let storyboar: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
let vs = storyboar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: idName)
vs.transitioningDelegate = animator as UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
self.present(vs, animated: animateBool, completion:nil)
```

現状ではこのような手法で画面遷移を行なっています。
また、画面遷移時のアニメーションは以下のサイトを参考にしております。

"UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioningを使って画面遷移アニメーションを作る"
https://qiita.com/kitoko552/items/4c0e411ff6224090db87

しかし、この方法だけで行き来した場合、メモリが消去されないためメモリリークが発生することが分かっています。
普段であればdismissを使った画面遷移で対応するのですが、dismissを使った場合、画面遷移アニメーションをどこに挟めば良いのかが分かりません。

CATransitionを使えばアニメーションは実装できましたが、UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioningを使って画面遷移を行うにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。
以下はdismissとCATransitionを使った例になります。

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)        
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

メモリリークを解決することがミッションのため
①presentを使って画面遷移前のメモリを消去する方法
②dismissを使ってカスタムアニメーションを実装する方法
のどちらかについてご回答して頂けましたら大変助かります。

勿論、もっと良いやり方がありましたらご教授願います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ①の方法はシステム的に新画面の表示であって、元画面に戻ることにはならないのでまったく問題外でしょう。リンク先の記事ではdismiss時のアニメーションも定義されているようですが、あなたのアプリではその部分がうまく動かないと言うことなのでしょうか?

Comment: リンク先の記事を見直して②を行うことは出来ました。私の認識だと、dismissは現状のViewを消すものであり、新しい画面を作りつつ既存の画面を削除することは出来ないと思うのですが、そういった方法はないのでしょうか。

Comment: ありません。[iOS View Controller プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS)あたりを熟読してみられると良いでしょう。もしそのような画面遷移が設計に盛り込まれてしまっているなら、WebViewを使うとか、そんな画面遷移ができるコンテナビューコントローラを自前で作るとか、「一度(見えないように)戻って改めて行く」などと言ったごまかしをするなんてことが必要になります。

Comment: そうでしたか。OOPer様、ご回答ありがとうございました。